# Is there a tidy way to handle null values in SQL "Select *" to prevent casting errors in c#/vb?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net

Lets say I have a the following query:

**SQL**

```
Select *
from tblExample
where Id = @Id
```

Values shouldn't usually have null values but sometimes do for reasons beyond my control.

Errors occur in when being assigned in the class properties e.g. (Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid):

**VB**

```
dim dr as DataRow = 'Data from Database'
Dim object1 As New myObject

object1.Number = CInt(dr("Number"))
object1.Name = CStr(dr("Name"))
object1.Active = CBool(dr("Active"))
```

**C#**

```
DataRow dr = //Data from Database
myObject object1 = new myObject();

object1.Number = (int)dr["Number"];
object1.Name = (string)dr["Name"];
object1.Active = (bool)dr["Active"];
```

Is there a shorter equivalent then writing out:

**SQL**

```
Select isnull(columnA, 0), isnull(columnB, ''), isnull(columnC, false)
from tblExample
where Id = @Id
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do not use "*"? That was bad style 50 years ago and it is bad style now.

Comment: Out of Curiosity, why @TomTom? In this case the every column is needed.

Comment: If you don't want to use `Isnull()` in your query then you have to handle it at code side like this - `dr["Number"] == DBNull.Value ? null :Convert.ToInt32(dr["Number"]);`. But personally I would prefer to go with the `Isnull` or `Coalesce` in sql.

Comment: Because it makes the code possibly get more data when needed when fields are addded later. It also does make it harder to get the values out without string field names - you can with a given field list use the ordinals without a lookup.

Comment: Thanks, @Krishnraj-Rana, I guess at that rate I isnull() would be easier.

Comment: `dr.Field<int?>("Number")` or `dr.Field<int?>("Number") ?? 0` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually need `DataRow` here? You could do it trivially in dapper:

```
int Id = ...
var object1 = conn.Query<ObjectType>("Select * from tblExample where Id = @Id",
    new { Id }).SingleOrDefault();
```

this will do all of the mapping for you, since the columns match, and will handle `null` correctly; after that, `object1.Number`, `.Name` and `.Active` will be as you expect.

Comment: This is quite interesting @Marc-Gravel, Is there a simple way to map the columns if the names were different? The database I'm usually calls its columns 'ObjectNumber', 'ObjectName', 'ObjectActive' etc.

Comment: @user no; dapper is opinionated and deliberately simple. Rather than having complicated mapping configurations, it joes for the "names match" approach.